# How to know each node state/statistics om veins/omnet?

Tags: omnet++, veins

How can we know which message is sent by which node and which node received it? When a car broadcasts a message, I want to know who all received it. Is there any way we can know the global knowledge?
I did see the log of packet traffic but how can I include more info into same? and how can I enable it in Express mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite hard to determine in a broadcasting environment, however your best chance is to create an extra simulation module (or just a class).

This `PacketMonitor` can behave like an *oracle* if you provide `packetSent()` and `packetReceived()` methods.

You will need to assign IDs to each message and then use the aforementioned methods to "register" the message in a table-like data structure of the `PacketMonitor` when a message is sent and received, respectively.

This is not a very complicated solution but it requires proper design and some extra thought on how to capture all of the potential scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I also had thought of something similar but storing message ID when a message sent are more than 10000, I was thinking of something like displaying message ID sent and received as in packet traffic window. Also, is there any way some logs can be enabled in Express mode?

Comment: The best way is normally to use the OMNeT++ statistics framework, as described [in the manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:signal-based-statistics). That allows you to generate output for any simulation, and it will be orders of magnitude faster than manual logging. It depends on what exactly you want to do with the result, though. OMNeT++ already gives you unique message identifiers (`beacon->getTreeId()`).

Comment: @RensvanderHeijden which version of OMNeT++ do you use, asking for the `getTreeId()`. For future reference: I have used the `getId()` which is embedded to each `AirFrame` message when they are created: `frame->setId(world->getUniqueAirFrameId());`

Comment: TreeID gives you a unique identifier for the message, while getID gives you a unique identifier for the specific copy of the message. See also [the documentation](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:messages:message-ids).